# What is the VS Code TextMate syntax for JSON inside an HTML attribute

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to add a grammar rule similar to the one [found here](https://github.com/panoply/vscode-json-script-tag/blob/master/syntax/script-json.embedded.json).  What that rule does is enable VSCode's JSON editor when it encounters an html file with

```
<script type="application/json">#Edit JSON</script>
```

What I would like is the same JSON editor support whenever it encounters a html attribute in this form:

```
<my-chart data='{"hello": "world"}'></my-chart>
```

In other words, any attribute that uses single quotes, inside of which it starts with a { and ends with a }, or starts with a [ and ends with a ].

Any suggestions what that should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've basically [found a way](https://github.com/bahrus/json-in-html/blob/baseline/syntax/script-json.embedded.json).  WIP